# cellForRowAtIndexPath method data are change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
 NSDictionary* dict2   = AppDelegate_Object.MyAssociates[indexPath.row];
 NSURL* url            = [NSURL URLWithString:dict2[@"Bcode"]];
 NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                                   NSData * data,
                                                   NSError * error) {
                                   if (!error){
                                       UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                     cell.ImageVc.image=image;
                                   }

                               }];
```

I use this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath for show image but when i scroll the table images are change what is I am doing wrong. please help me???

Comment: you are calling the URL everytime a new cell appears on the view ie. everytime you scroll, URL gets called.

Comment: @Mr.T  how to fix this bug please tell me

Comment: this shouldnt be a problem,anyway you are calling it asynchronous. What does the URL return ?

Comment: You are loading the images asynchronously, by that time the cell reference can be re-used. You should properly handle this situation or use third-party library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: You may be having problems with the references on the callback. You should consider using a pod such as [AsynchronousImageView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/M13AsynchronousImageView) to deal with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me take example what is happening in your code. Let say you have **4** row in your tableview **A, B, C and D,** when you want to download image of **row A** as it is asynchronous call, and then you scroll table view.... **row A** exchange with **row B** or **row C** or **row D**. As output, image of **row A**, can be displayed in to **row B** or **row C** or **row D** .

To solve this issue you will have to hold the reference of imageview or you get reference of that imageview at run time once your image is download.

Comment: sir , how to hold reference of imageview and get it please explain me

Comment: @LCNagar you can use create imageview cateogry , there you can implement asynchronous call.